# Powershell script equivalent of database -> Generate scripts

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script which stores schema, and data info in `.sql` file.
But in that file I am missing the initiate part of `create database`. The file starts with queries of `create table`.

PowerShell script:

```
$Filepath= 'C:\Temp' # local directory to save build-scripts to
$DataSource= 'ServerName' #'SERVERNAME' # server name and instance
$Database= 'DBName'

$DateTime = Get-Date -Format s
$dateStamp = $(get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
$ms='Microsoft.SqlServer'
$v = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "$ms.SMO")
if ((($v.FullName.Split(','))[1].Split('='))[1].Split('.')[0] -ne '9') {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("$ms.SMOExtended") | out-null
   }
$My="$ms.Management.Smo" #
$s = new-object ("$My.Server") $DataSource
if ($s.Version -eq  $null ){Throw "Can't find the instance $Datasource"}
$db= $s.Databases[$Database] 
if ($db.name -ne $Database){Throw "Can't find the database '$Database' in $Datasource"};
$transfer = new-object ("$My.Transfer") $db
$transfer.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true
$transfer.Options.ToFileOnly = $true
$transfer.Options.ScriptData = $true
$transfer.Options.IncludeHeaders = $true
$transfer.Options.ExtendedProperties = $true
$transfer.Options.IncludeDatabaseContext = $true
$transfer.Options.DriForeignKeys = $true
$transfer.Options.DriIndexes = $true
$transfer.Options.DriPrimaryKey = $true
$transfer.Options.DriUniqueKeys = $true

$transfer.CreateTargetDatabase = $true
$transfer.Options.Filename = "$($FilePath)\$($Database)_$($dateStamp)_Build.sql"; 
$transfer.EnumScriptTransfer()
```

Any help on how this can be achieved?
Basically I am missing `create database` block in my `.sql` file.

Comment: Use one of the SQL command line utilities.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/overview-sql-tools?view=sql-server-ver16  No need to use Reflection.  You code is missing the connection string and the open.  I usually use SQLCMD.EXE.  To debug I usually recommend test in SQL Server Management Studio.  When testing in PS you can get error logs in SSMS in the explorer under Management.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you! The script is working. It's able to export schema and data into .sql file. It's just that in that sql file create database block isn't there. If I generate the same file from SSMS, it has create database query block as well.

Comment: What error do you see in SSMS when the script is run from PS?  Probably there is issue with credentials.  The SSMS logs will show the login errors when PS is run.  Look at login window on SSMS.  It will give the Server name and Instance.  Same should be used from PS.   Also login will indicate that if Windows Credential or SQL Credentials are used.  When SSMS shows Windows Credentials the  the PS connection string should have Integrated Security = true.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to add an extra line where you script the database info, instead of the objects.

I think, based on your script, it would be something like this:

```
$db.Script() | Out-File 'c:\temp\database.sql'
```

Change the path and file name as you see fit.